# "Server Error" with G+ API on APP engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

I've a problem with Google+ API on my app engine .

I tried my codes on my own hosting and it worked well , I don't know why it gives me a server error when I deploy my code on the app engine .

Firstly here's the G+ code with file named (index.php) :

```
<?php


require_once 'Google_Client.php';
require_once 'Google_PlusService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");

//Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
//client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('55845591562.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('J-l4j5yxhVsCfrfRHVy1x8IF');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://fictionteam.com/fb/');
$client->setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyCNDNQn7A9M2COPaW1NOYpZEoaiXCNibZ4');
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die("The session state did not match.");
  }
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  print "Your Profile: <pre>" . print_r($me, true) . "</pre>";

  $params = array('maxResults' => 100);
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $params);
  print "Your Activities: <pre>" . print_r($activities, true) . "</pre>";

  $params = array(
    'orderBy' => 'best',
    'maxResults' => '20',
  );
  $results = $plus->activities->search('Google+ API', $params);
  foreach($results['items'] as $result) {
    print "Search Result: <pre>{$result['object']['content']}</pre>\n";
  }

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

Also Here's the app.yaml configuration :

```
application: gcdc2013-troubles
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php
```

I put all API library on the same directory of app engine files , but when I access to my app engine link it gives  me  "Server Error"

[gcdc2013-troubles.appspot.com](http://gcdc2013-troubles.appspot.com)

Comment: You need to look at the error you are getting in the log.

Comment: Here's the log file :
http://pastebin.com/APZyUaEV

Comment: This line of you log is somewhat telling  `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension'`  I know nothing about PHP but one would assume you need to resolve these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions for setting up the Google API client [here](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/08/06/using-the-google-apis-client-library-for-php-with-app-engine/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you include/uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll` in your `php.ini`?

Also, it looks like `urlfetch` is preferred over `cURL` on GAE.